# In which pant-pocket should I keep wallet, handkerchief and phone?

Tags: personal-care, phone, packaging, safety

Currently I put handkerchief, mobile phone and keys in right front pocket, and the wallet in left one. But I figured out some issues:

- If I put keys and mobile in same pocket phone screen gets scratches
- If handkerchief is wet, I wish not to put it with mobile
- If handkerchief is put with comb, pen(If wearing pocketless shirt), takes them accidently out.
- I wish not to put phone and wallet in rear pockets, because they can be easily pickpocketed or damaged.

Tell me how do you tackle these issue?
What would be right place of all these regular things?

Comment: The answers below are clever and logical. I would add that depending on the number of keys you have, you may be able to store them inside your wallet, on a beaded chain (or something similar) rather than a ring. They won't scratch anything that way.

Comment: you're carrying a lot of stuff around! I try to keep myself to wallet, phone, keys and handkerchief, although i do use my rear pocket for the wallet. maybe you should consider cargo pants, or maybe a bum bag/fanny pack

Answer (score 1):

- You could keep your handkerchief in one of your rear pockets, as it wouldn't be a problem to sit on it or getting it pickpocketed.
- Front pockets are often like V shaped : you can put your keys in the bottom of the V of one of the pockets, depending of your handedness or preference, then you can keep your mobile above the keys, protected in a cover.
- In the other front pocket, you could keep your wallet, and slip the pen along it in the pocket.

It is the configuration I am actually using, the only problem you could face is a big wallet making an unsightly lump on the front of your trousers.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep Mobile and Handkerchief in the same pocket (handkerchief above the mobile) this will protect your mobile from external shock. If handkerchief is wet then also it should not damage the mobile because external body of mobiles are water resistant to some extent. For extra safety you can put a cover on your mobile phone.

In other pocket you can keep wallet, keys and pen and you can put the comb in the rear pocket.